# Can Enterprise logging library throw an exception?

Tags: c#

I have a service that seems to die once in a while. I have tried catching the unhandled exception (using appDomain method) but to no avail.

Looking at my code, I can see exception handling code around certain places. However, there is not exception handling code when I am writing to a log file via enterprise library.

My questions is, should I put exception handling around the enterprise library code in case it throws an exception or is it reliable enough to handle any problems?

JD,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What will you do if the logging block *does* throw an exception?  You obviously can't log it so I would say no, don't catch that exception.  Only catch exceptions that you can handle and do something meaningful with - a caught exception around logging simply means that you will be hiding the fact that real errors are not getting logged.

Comment: That's kind of what logging is for. On a production server or a desktop client, you don't want exceptions causing systems to falter. Catch the exception, log it, and let the system go on with its merry day. If it's a major exception, this is still the right way to handle it. Find where the exception occurs and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I do not catch it, it is probably the one that is bringing down my service. At the moment, I am not sure if this is why my service is dying occasionally. My application retires after the exception, so yes I wont have the real error but at least it can recover.

Comment: Have you looked at the Windows event log?

Comment: Before I use to get "windows service terminated unexpectedly". Now, nothing at all is logged. I tried using AppDomain.UnExcepted.... but that was not getting called even when I intentionally threw an exception.

Comment: Okay, I have set Debugger.Break() in my code and attached the debugger to the service. I saw some strange exceptions which I hope to get resolved soon, however, when writing to the log file, I got :

{"The type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct or that the full type name is provided."}

Now, is this because I am in the debugger or does this answer my ?

Comment: I think that answers your question :) Verify that the assembly exists.

Comment: Weird why I get this error sometimes and not all the time. Anyway, I have put a try/except around the log handling and we have not had the service go down in days. Thanks for all the help.