# Should logging code throw an Exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm designing a small library which should help logging into different destinations (files, databases, etc.). However, I'm not sure if I should throw exceptions if something goes wrong (e.g. a file cannot be written to)?

**If I throw exceptions** (related to logging), the developer of applications using my library can clearly see that logging does not happen as intended. On the other hand, it can be an additional source of problems.

**If I suppress exceptions** and just quietly not log, the developer may miss important information if e.g. the database cannot be reached.

Are there any suggestions, general guidelines (if a then b, etc.) on how to approach this?

---

**As I have read so far:**

[Microsofts Guidelines for Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229030(v=vs.110).aspx) state:

> ✗ DO NOT have public members that can either throw or not based on some option.

So an option whether or not to throw an exception would be against these guidelines, but they do not give statements on throwing exceptions if it is uncertain how likely an exception is.

I also read in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223116/can-enterprise-logging-library-throw-an-exception) that I should not catch exceptions because I cannot do anything meaningful with them, but the question was targeting an Enterprise-level system, while my question asks on a more general level.

Comment: This seems to be a design decision. I don't think there is a absolute correct answer.

Comment: ^ Agreed. This seems more appropriate for https://programmers.stackexchange.com/, although it may still not meet the general requirements for a Stack Exchange question since answers could be opinionated.

Comment: One possibility might be to output exceptions to `Trace`. They can use your library to log normally, but they can choose to configure `Trace`, and log errors will write to a file or to the Windows Event Log, which should always succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not dogmatically follow any guidelines.  Consult the guidelines, and then do what you think is best for solving the problem at hand.

A logger is a special piece of software: it has special needs and considerations.  Therefore, the guidelines issued by microsoft do not apply to your logger in exactly the same way as they apply to general purpose software.

In my book, it is perfectly fine to vary your logger's behavior based on an "Is-This-A-Development-Environment" flag, and to throw exceptions if `true`, or suppress these exceptions (possibly logging them in some less-error-prone medium) otherwise.

Comment: Very true. I did not consider this before, actually!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, just this week I added a new NLog target to one of my applications and it didn't log, but didn't complain about that either. So it struck me that the NLog team has made this decision in regard to failing log targets. I can tell you that NLog silently fails to log to a target.

However - not completely. They do have an internal logger which you can use to debug the logger: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging
Which you can configure like so:

```
<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">
   <targets>
      <!-- target configuration here -->
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <!-- log routing rules -->
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

Since NLog ( together with Log4Net ) are probably the biggest logging libraries for .NET, this might be of interest to you.

Another thing I've seen is that some libraries reference https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging/ which I find very elegant. It's a very lightweight package with a set of interfaces you can use to log against. The calling assembly then controls what happens to the output by using an adapter for NLog or Log4Net and keep using the pre-existing targets.

Comment: NLog's strategy only moves the problem around, it does not solve it. What happens if the `C:` disk is full (or the user's quotas are exceeded) while using the internal logger? Would it throw then?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already have stated, this is a design decision, so there's no answer that is correct in a technical sense.

I normally do it like this:

- If something goes wrong, then I do throw an exception as a first attempt.
- I catch this exception inside the logging framework itself and write it to the system's event log (which should always succeed).
- If that also fails for some reason, I swallow the error silently.
- Optionally, you might rethrow the exception in debug version or write it to debug output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that there are many cases where the quoted statement from Microsoft should be ignored.  What I would suggest for as a pattern for a logging class would be to have a method which returns a "log suppression" token and then stifles exceptions that would occur during logging, but then have a method which cancels the effect of the log-suppression token and, depending upon a passed-in parameter, either returns a list of exceptions that have been suppressed or else, when the list is non-empty, throws a composite exception containing the list.  I would further suggest that the logging request require that the tokens be used in last-in-first-out fashion, and that failure to cancel the effects of one before cancelling the effects of an earlier-created one should be considered an exception-worthy usage error.

Even though it goes against Microsoft's advice, having a method throw or not based upon a parameter offers two advantages that cannot be obtained otherwise:

1. There are many situations where an operation which would support a try/do pattern calls methods which support the same pattern.  If public try/do methods chain to a method which uses a parameter to distinguish between "try" and "do", and the nested methods to be called also support such a parameter, then it's possible to have the "try" and "do" methods share the same implementation.  If all public methods are either "try-only" or "do-only", "do" wants problems in the inner methods to appear as exceptions thrown by them, and the "try" doesn't want to nested "do" methods to throw exceptions it will have to catch, then even if callers try to use shared code internally, they'll end up having to:

   ```
   if (throwOnException)
   {
     thing.ReadData(whatever);
     success = true;
   }
   else
   {
     success = thing.TryReadData(whatever);
   }
   ```

   a fragment of code large enough that it should be its own method, but which semantically belongs more to `thing` than the client.
2. A `try`/`finally` block should only exit without throwing an exception if everything succeeds within both the `try` and `finally` sections.  If an exception occurs in the `try`, however, it is often better to have that exception propagate than to have it be overwritten by an exception which is thrown in the `finally`.  Oftentimes, the behavior of the `finally` code will be the same whether the `try` block succeeded or not, *except* that exceptions which occur when the `try` block succeeded should be allowed to propagate while those that occur when the `try` block failed should be stifled.

Neither C# nor VB provides a nice way for a `finally` block to know whether the `try` succeeded, but it is possible.  If the `finally` block will sometimes want things to throw exceptions and sometimes stifle them, but otherwise behave identically, having a parameter to select problem-reporting behavior will be cleaner than having to use separate code for the pending-exception and no-pending-exception scenarios.